# Jasmine continuous integration with Atlassian Bamboo Play Framework 1 possible?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, playframework, jasmine

I've been scratching my head the whole day trying to find a way for bamboo to run Jasmine JS unit test as part of CI.

I've followed quite a lot of guide, starting from using jasmine-maven-plugin, then following:

1. http://semaphoreci.com/blog/2013/05/28/jasmine-javascript-tests-for-continuous-integration.html
2. https://kumikoro.wordpress.com/2015/12/03/javascript-test-coverage-in-bamboo/

And some other tutorials I can't post the link to since i don't have enough reputation.

I've read you need test runner like Karma to integrate JS unit testing as part of CI and need PhantomJS to run it headlessly, and then convert the test report to JUnit report for bamboo to parse.

However the important component which is Karma seems to be only available in Node JS? Possibly Angular JS?

Now we don't use any JS framework. So is there alternative? If not does that mean I need to integrate Play Framework 1 with Angular?